# Dominance Poisson/Binomial in convex order

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions

Given two r.v. $X,Y$ (with well-defined expectations) such that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$, we say that *$X$ is dominated by $Y$ in the convex order*, denoted $X \leq_{\rm cx} Y$, if
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)] \leq \mathbb{E}[f(Y)]
$$
for every convex function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, provided the expectations exist.

Given $n\geq 1$, $p\in[0,1]$, let $\lambda := np$, and $X,Y$ be distributed as $\textrm{Binomial}(n,p)$ and $\textrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, respectively.

> Is it true that $X \leq_{\rm cx} Y$? If so, what would be a good reference or proof for this fact?

This seems to follow from Theorem 2.2 of [1], but I may be misreading -- and, in any case, this result is much more general, it would fill like overkill to use it.

[1] Negative dependence and stochastic orderings, Fraser Daly (2015). https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06493

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

That is exactly the statement of Lemma 2.3 in [1].

*For any convex function $f$, any integer $N \geqslant 1$ and parameter $p\in [0,1]$, we have
$$
E\left[f\left( Bin(N, p)\right) \right] \leqslant E\left[f\left( Poi(Np)\right) \right].
$$*

There is also a book [2] with a million theorems of this nature.

---

[1] Barman, Fawzi, Ghoshal, Gürpinar. *Tight Approximation Bounds for
Maximum Multi-Coverage*, IPCO 2020 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.00640)

[2] M. Shaked and J.G. Shanthikumar. *Stochastic Orders*. (10.1007/978-0-387-34675-5)

Comment: Thank you! I have to say, I skimmed [2] and couldn't find this statement among the million theorems.

Answer (score 10):

This follows from the fact that ${\rm Poi}(p)$ dominates ${\rm Bin}(1,p)$, and adding $n$ independent copies of these.

To see that $Y\sim{\rm Poi}(p)$ dominates $X\sim{\rm Bin}(1,p)$, note that
$$
\mathbb P(X=0)=1-p\le e^{-p}=\mathbb P(Y=0).
$$
Hence, we can couple these so that $\{X=0\}\subseteq\{Y=0\}$ is an event of probability $1-p$.
Then, $Y=0$ whenever $X=0$ so we obtain,
$$
\mathbb E[Y\vert X]=X.
$$
This holds when $X=0$ since both sides equal $0$, and hence also holds for $X=1$ since both sides have expectation $p$.
This shows that $Y$ dominates $X$ since $f(X)\le\mathbb E[f(Y)\vert X]$ for convex $f$ by Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Nice. Here, you're using the fact that the convex order is closed under convolutions in the end (just adding it here for my own (and possibly others') reference, this is, e.g., Theorem 3.A.12 of *Stochastic Orders* by Shaked and Shanthikumar).